# C#: Storing delegate lists that accept a derived type

Tags: c#, event-handling, delegates

I have a Holder class that is passed Instructions. I want other classes to be able to register delegates with the holder so that when a certain type of Instruction is passed to it, the delegate gets executed. What's the right way to implement this?

I feel like there's some common design pattern, possibly involving EventHandler, but I'm not sure what it is. I'm trying to avoid making the delegate functions accept Instruction and then the first line of the function is always casting it to the correct derived type.

Here is a non-working example of what I want, two classes registering their functions with the types they care about. It doesn't compile because I'm trying to add a delegate that accepts a derived type where the dictionary value is for delegates that accept the parent type.

```
    abstract class Instruction { }
    class InstructionA : Instruction { }
    class InstructionB : Instruction { }

    // I want this to accept the relevant derived class instead of Instruction.
    delegate void InstructionDelegate(Instruction instruction);

    class Holder {
        public Dictionary<Type, List<InstructionDelegate>> delegateLists = new Dictionary<Type, List<InstructionDelegate>>();
        public void ProcessInstruction(Instruction instruction) {
            foreach (var f in delegateLists[typeof(Instruction)]) {
                f(instruction);
            }
        }
    }

    class SomeClass {
        SomeClass(Holder holder) {
            holder.delegateLists[typeof(InstructionA)].Add(HandleInstructionA);  // doesn't compile
        }
        void HandleInstructionA(InstructionA a) { }
    }

    class OtherClass {
        OtherClass(Holder holder) {
            holder.delegateLists[typeof(InstructionA)].Add(HandleInstructionA);  // doesn't compile
            holder.delegateLists[typeof(InstructionB)].Add(HandleInstructionB);  // doesn't compile
        }
        void HandleInstructionA(InstructionA a) { }
        void HandleInstructionB(InstructionB b) { }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you implement a virtual `Execute()` method in `Instruction` that can be overridden by your derived class?  You can then store Instruction classes, instantiate InstructionA and InstructionB classes, and it should just do the right thing.  See "runtime polymorphism."

Comment: The Instruction class and derivations are actually from another dll, so don't think I can alter the Instruction class like that here.